# mouseup not firing in Chrome on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, windows-7

I'm using [dragdealer](http://code.ovidiu.ch/dragdealer/) for a custom scrollbar on my site. What I just discovered, is that in Chrome on Windows 7, when you click on the scrollbar button and move it, the button gets "stuck" and moves whenever you move the mouse.
You can see this behavior in any of the scrollbars on the page linked above. This doesn't happen in any other browser, nor does it happen with the exact same Chrome release (24.0.1312.56 m) in Windows XP.

Is there a way for me to "force" the `mouseup` when the user releases the mouse button? Or any other solution?

TIA!

Comment: FYI There are no problems with Win 7 Enterprise edition, I've tried the link with Chrome and the scroll bars function as they should without sticking.

Comment: It is a known bug that shows up sometimes in Chrome. http://www.google.com.co/search?q=chrome+scrollbar+stick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the culprit was the Babylon translation extension I had in Chrome! Once I disabled it, everything worked the way it should...!